# Swagger: How to use password format (Parameter annotation) for a String field ? Currently it won't allow me to submit the form with a value

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui

I have a Spring Boot app (2.7.0) with spring docs (1.6.9)

Endpoint defined as follows:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/upload", consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
    @Operation(summary = "blah blah blah")
    public ResponseEntity<UploadSummary> uploadData(
            @RequestParam("file") final MultipartFile csvFile,
            @Parameter(schema = @Schema(type = "string", format = "password"))
            @RequestParam("password") final String password,
            @RequestParam(name = "dryRun", required = false, defaultValue = "true") final boolean dryRun) {
```

I want to have the password input field on the Swagger interface mask the input. The only change I have made above is to include a single @Parameter annotation, nothing else.

[image]

The Swagger interface does not appear to like this single Parameter annotation at all, regardless of format. If I input a value in the password field, it is always highlighted with a red border and I cannot execute.

I tried upgrading to 1.6.12 but still doesn't work.

Perhaps other annotations or code needs to be setup before these Parameter annotations and Schema types work ?

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but the annotations seem to be incorrect. Those parameters are generated as query parameters, whereas they are supposed to be form data fields. Check the docs to see how to correctly annotate multipart request bodies.

Comment: The red input issue happens because the parameter type appears to be generated incorrectly. As seen on the screenshot, the password parameter type appears as `String($password)` (with the uppercase "S"), but it should be `string($password)` (with the lowercase "s" in "string"). I don't know what the correct annotations should be though.

Comment: Aha, checking with the lower case string. I may have done that :)

Comment: @Helen well spotted ! That is indeed the answer. What a star! If you want the credit, please add an answer

Comment: Feel free to post an answer yourself to show how you fixed those annotations.